# Site migration and how to write internal links with migration in mind

Tags: links, migration, customization, https

Hi Hope some one doesn't mind explaining this?

I'm going to work on a replacement site while keeping the old one live, two questions here:

1. How do I fool my PC to direct to the new installation? I want to use `www.example.com` and it point to the I.P of the new installation so I can keep all the internal links the same when I migrate.
2. How should I write my internal hyper links in my new build? When I migrate the site it will have SSL but not while in development.
   I've not used internal links before I've always used the full path i.e `<a href="https://www.example.com/blog/">Visit our blog</a>`
   my dev site won't be SSL so I don't want to stipulate the full path as it will cause 301's when I migrate and slow the site down as I would have to use http:// to do the build.
   How do I write an internal link? Would it just be `<a href="blog">visit our blog</a>` ?

Many thanks

Ben

Comment: Export your database. Download a copy of your root of the site. Download Sublime Text, open the database sql file, and `CTRL+h` to replace `www.oldexample.com` with `www.newexample.com`. Do the same thing for the site files but this tile with `CTRL+shift+f` then you upload the files to the root of new site, import the database and then you must be done. Done this many times as migrating from shared to VPS.

Comment: Forgot to mention: Do not change the DB credentials while importing otherwise update them in the `wp-config.php` file